# Find the difference between the max value and 2nd highest value within a subset of pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a fairly large dataframe:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 17 | 36 | 45 | 54 |
| 1 | 18 | 23 | 17 | 17 |
| 2 | 74 | 47 | 8 | 46 |
| 3 | 48 | 38 | 96 | 83 |

I am trying to create a new column that is the (max value of the columns) - (2nd highest value) / (2nd highest value).

In this example it would look something like:

|  | A | B | C | D | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 17 | 36 | 45 | 54 | .20 |
| 1 | 18 | 23 | 17 | 17 | .28 |
| 2 | 74 | 47 | 8 | 46 | .57 |
| 3 | 48 | 38 | 96 | 83 | .16 |

I've tried df['diff'] = df.loc[:, 'A': 'D'].max(axis=1) - df.iloc[:df.index.get_loc(df.loc[:, 'A': 'D'].idxmax(axis=1))] / ...

but even that part of the formula returns an error, nevermind including the final division.  I'm sure there must be an easier way going about this.

Edit:  Additionally, I am also trying to get the difference between the max value and the column that immediately precedes the max value.  I know this is a somewhat different question, but I would appreciate any insight.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

One way using `pandas.Series.nlargest` with `pct_change`:

```
df["Diff"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).pct_change(-1)[0], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D      Diff
0  17  36  45  54  0.200000
1  18  23  17  17  0.277778
2  74  47   8  46  0.574468
3  48  38  96  83  0.156627
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to apply a udf:

```
def get_pct(x):
    xmax2, xmax = x.sort_values().tail(2)
    return (xmax-xmax2)/xmax2

df['Diff'] = df.apply(get_pct, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D      Diff
0  17  36  45  54  0.200000
1  18  23  17  17  0.277778
2  74  47   8  46  0.574468
3  48  38  96  83  0.156627
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did not include this question in my original post.  But is it possible to obtain the difference between the column with the highest value, and the column that is immediately before it (no matter it's value):  (ColumnMax.value - columnmax.column - 1.value)?

Answer (score 2):

We can also make use of numpy sort and np.diff :

```
arr = np.sort(df,axis=1)[:,-2:]
df['Diff'] = np.diff(arr,axis=1)[:,0]/arr[:,0]
```

---

```
print(df)

    A   B   C   D      Diff
0  17  36  45  54  0.200000
1  18  23  17  17  0.277778
2  74  47   8  46  0.574468
3  48  38  96  83  0.156627
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try get the second Max value with `mask`

```
Max = df.max(1)
secMax = df.mask(df.eq(Max,0)).max(1)
df['Diff'] = (Max - secMax)/secMax
df
Out[69]: 
    A   B   C   D      Diff
0  17  36  45  54  0.200000
1  18  23  17  17  0.277778
2  74  47   8  46  0.574468
3  48  38  96  83  0.156627
```